# Catch dynamic URL change in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a Vue component.

In this component I have a button that changes the URL of the page dynamically by adding it to the browser history:

```
window.history.pushState({},"", window.location.href + '/topic');
```

On this change, the page should display some information. I tried using a computed property for this purpose:

```
currentRoute : function () {

            let route_parts = window.location.href.split("/");
            if(route_parts[route_parts.length - 1] === "topic")
                return "topic";

            return "home";

        }
```

However, this doesn't work. When I try to use the computed property to determined which element to show and which to hide, the condition is not true after the URL changes in the browser:

```
<span v-if="currentRoute === 'topic'">This topic is an interesting topic.</span>
```

If I reload the page after changing the URL in this way, the condition is true and this element is visible. So the problem lies in the computed property not reacting to the URL change.

How can I handle this?

Comment: Vue computed props works only when the logic inside use some reactive state (data, another computed) of the Vue component. If not, the value is computed only once and never recomputed again (as Vue doesn't know it should be recomputed)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Computed property is not the answer to observe external world and recompute the value. Browser's Location/Address bar is external change. For this purpose, you can use either [`popstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event) event or [`hashchange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event) event depending on the part of URL change you need to listen.

In your case, you probably need `popstate` event. Use `created` or `mounted` hook to register for event.

```
const component = {
  mounted() {

    const urlChange = () => {
      // Do your logic here
    };

    window.addEventListener('popstate', urlChange);

    // Useful for cleanup when component is destroyed
    this.cleanup = urlChange;
  },

  // Or use destroyed
  beforeDestroy() {
    // It is important to remove the handler when component is getting destroyed
    window.removeEventListener('popstate', this.cleanup);
  }
};
```

On a side note, if you are using routing with history state, I strongly suggest that you use `vue-router`. It handles many edges cases.